# Determine which PHP script executes a specific mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to know which PHP script is executing a certain mysql query?

I'm using a prebuilt system which has a bunch of files and I'm seeing one query I want to investigate but no idea where to start looking.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try searching for non-variable parts of the query in the source files directly (e.g. using your IDE's search function, or using `grep -r 'some part of the query'`).

If you can't find it, try [tracing function calls with xdebug](http://xdebug.org/docs/execution_trace). This will log all PHP function calls, and it will be easy to find which file did mysql_query(the query).

(Set the ini setting `xdebug.collect_params` to `3` to get the parameter values in the log file.)